# Mongodb numbers in collection name

Tags: mongodb, collections, names

i'm playing around with mongodb from some weeks ago, and suddenly appeared collections with duplicate names and a number attached to it some like:

```
coleccion_nueva_56b41cc944bd390932e79827
```

I don't know why this collection appeared suddenly, if that is good, bad or normal and what to do with it.

Comment: That number *56b41cc944bd390932e79827* looks like an ObjectId. Is there a record somewhere in your database with that id?

Comment: Are you running any apps against your mongodb instance? Are there any documents in these collections (which would give you a good hint where they're coming from)? Is your mongodb instance accessible from the outside world, without any security (meaning someone else can easily connect and use your database)? There's really no way to answer your question here (at least with the information you provided).

Comment: That database is for test everithing i learn, is used for a test scala app, it is sharded, use standar ports and dont have any security.

Comment: It is in a VPS, and every of the ten collections have a copy with it name and that exactly number every time:
miscosas
miscosas_56b41cc944bd390932e79827
reglamentos
reglamentos_56b41cc944bd390932e79827
coleccion_nueva
coleccion_nueva_56b41cc944bd390932e79827
etc